# GridView Column TextWrap like Excel in c# windows

Tags: c#, windows, gridview

I have a grid view containing column names a bit lengthy which are coming from database. So i want to make the wrapping like what we do in Excel in multiline rather than making the column fit to the length.
I used

```
dataGridView1.Columns["abcdefghijklmnop"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
dataGridView1.Columns["abcdefghijklmnop"].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode=DataGridViewTriState.True;
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

When i do this i am able to fit the column length to the text length.but i want it to be in multiline.

Example : Should be like this

```
-------------------------------------------------
      | abcde | klmno | uvwxy |
      | fghij | pqrst | z     |
-------------------------------------------------
Team1 |       |       |       |
Team2 |       |       |       |
TeamN |       |       |       |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Now it is coming like this

```
-------------------------------------------------
      | abcdefghij | klmnopqrst | uvwxyz |
      |            |            |        |
-------------------------------------------------
Team1 |       |       |       |
Team2 |       |       |       |
TeamN |       |       |       |
-------------------------------------------------
```

these are the properties i am having 
[image]
Pls help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it many ways for example:

```
![dataGridView1.Columns\[0\].HeaderText = "VeryLong " + "LongLong" + Environment.NewLine + "LongLongLong";][1]
```

[image]
OR

```
dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 
    DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;

foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
{
    column.HeaderCell.Style.WrapMode= DataGridViewTriState.True;
}
```

Finally through edit datagridview columns manually:

[image]

Comment: My column names are coming from database dynamically,i tried the secind way but no result